# How to temporarily display a view before ContentView()?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building an app based on a large static database.
Each time I open the app, I would like to check that its local database has been created from a JSON-encoded file.
If this is not the case (i.e. the first time the app is opened), the data is decoded from the JSON-encoded file and inserted into the database.

This process takes about 10 seconds during which I would like to display a `ProgressView()` before the user has access to the interface (i.e. `ContentView()`).

**EDIT - here is the solution:**

```
class DatabaseBuilder: ObservableObject {
    $Published var isBuilding = true

    let database = SomeDatabase()

    private func decodeJSON() async throws {
        // long process to decode large JSON-encoded file
    }

    private func fillDatabase() async throws {
        // long process to add new model objects to database
    }

    public func build() async throws {
        if !database.isEmpty {
            isBuilding = false
        }

        try await decodeJSON()
        try await fillDatabase()

        isBuilding = false
    }
}
```

```
struct LargeDatabaseApp: App {
    @StateObject var builder = DatabaseBuilder()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .opacity(builder.isBuilding ? 0 : 1)
                .overlay { if builder.isBuilding { ProgressView() } }
                .task {
                    do {
                        try await builder.build()
                    } catch {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show ProgressView as an `overlay` over ContentView or whatever.

Comment: You are initializing two different DatabaseBuilders.

Comment: just show your content view normally and change its subview from progress view to target view when database loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct LargeDatabaseApp: App {
    @StateObject var builder = DatabaseBuilder()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if builder.isBuilding {
                ProgressView(){Label("building db", systemImage: "stopwatch")}
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
            Spacer().frame(height: 0)
                .onAppear {
                    if builder.database.isEmpty {
                        do {
                            try builder.build()
                        }
                        catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

class DatabaseBuilder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isBuilding = false
    var database = ""
    
    public func build() throws {
        isBuilding = true
        // builds database...
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            self.isBuilding = false
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ContentView here")
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: you could also try using the `scenePhase`, like this:

```
@main
struct LargeDatabaseApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    @StateObject var builder = DatabaseBuilder()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if builder.isBuilding {
                ProgressView(){Label("building db", systemImage: "stopwatch")}
            } else {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .background:
                print("time to write to your database")
                break
            case .active:
                print("setup the database")
                if builder.database.isEmpty {
                    do {
                        try builder.build()
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
                break
            case .inactive:
                print("inactive")
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your logic is working. However, despite having replaced `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { ... }` by `DispatchQueue.main.async { // decoding JSON and filling database... }`, the `ProgressView()` is never displayed during the construction of the database. The `ContentView()` is displayed immediately. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: is `decoding JSON and filling database...` itself an async function from which you return when completed? Could you show what you do in that function.

Comment: To check the time it takes to do your processing, in `DatabaseBuilder`,
 could you add `print("---> start time: \(Date())")` just before `isBuilding = true`,
 and `print("---> finish time: \(Date())")` just after `isBuilding = false`, ie, when the 
`decoding JSON and filling database...` finishes.

Comment: The `build()` function performs 2 steps :
`try self.decodeJSONDatabase() ` then `try self.fetchAndAddModelObjects()`. The first one simply decodes a large JSON file into Decodable instances : `try decoder.decode([CodableThing].self, from: data)`. The second instantiates the database model objects, then adds them to the database. It uses Swift Realm : `try realm.write { realm.add(Set(objects)) }`.

Comment: hard to tell exactly what you are doing. 
 I suggest that when all of the fetching/adding to Realm etc.. are done, you set `self.isBuilding = false`, not before.
 This probably means inside some closure.

Comment: I finally found the solution using `async/await` and setting `isBuilding` to `true` by default. Thanks for your help!